# How can I enable colored completion in Vim?

Tags: vim, tab-completion

I understand that this questions could be a bit unclear, but I think an example will help.

I'm in Vim and want to open a file. There are a few files in my directory and some have the same prefix. I used `wildmode=longest,list`. For 
example: Common.pm, Context.pm and Controller.pm. There are more files, but lets keep the example simple.

I want to open `Controller.pm`, so I type `:e` and `C`, followed by `<tab>`.

So now I see a list like this (pipe `|` is cursor):

```
Common.pm      Context.pm      Controller.pm
:e Co|
```

I need to type the next character that's different to choose the file I want, I need to type the `ntr` to choose the file. To make it easier to know which characters to type, Vim could highlight the next differing characters like this, but with a bright color instead of brackets.

```
Co[m]mon.pm      Co[nte]xt.pm      Co[ntr]oller.pm
:e Co|
```

Does this exist? Or is there a way to make this work with options or scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)

> The NERD tree allows you to explore your filesystem and to open files and
>   directories. It presents the filesystem to you in the form of a tree which you
>   manipulate with the keyboard and/or mouse. It also allows you to perform
>   simple filesystem operations.